# Asp.net syntax error for Command Argument in linkbutton

Tags: c#, asp.net, syntax, linkbutton

I am trying to use linkbutton inside of foreach in asp.net

I have below html.

**Asp.net html:**

```
<table border="1" style="grid-cell: inherit; border-spacing: inherit;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>İlan ID
                            </th>
                            <th>İlan Yolu
                            </th>
                            <th>Eklenme Tarihi
                            </th>
                            <th>İlk Güncelleme Tarihi
                            </th>
                            <th>Güncelleme Aralığı
                            </th>
                            <th>Son Güncelleme Tarihi
                            </th>
                            <th>Aktifmi
                            </th>
                            <th>Detay Göster
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <%foreach (var item in list)
                      {%>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center">
                            <span><%= item.Id%>    </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span><%=item.DosyaAdi %></span>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">
                            <span><%=item.EklemeTarihi %></span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span><%=item.IlkGuncellemeTarihi %></span>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">
                            <span><%=item.GuncellemeAraligi %></span>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">
                            <span><%=item.SonGuncelleme %></span>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="<%=item.Id %>" <%= item.Aktif ==true ? "checked='checked'" : "" %> />
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbdetay" runat="server" OnClick="lbdetay_Click" CommandArgument="<%=item.Id%>" CommandName="Detay">Detay</asp:LinkButton>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <%  } %>
                </table>
```

**Question:**

In part of linkbutton as below

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="lbdetay" runat="server" OnClick="lbdetay_Click" CommandArgument="<%=item.Id%>" CommandName="Detay">Detay</asp:LinkButton>
```

If i use **CommandArgument="<%=item.Id%>"** it is not working (**it displays syntax error here**)

Where i miss inside of code for command argument in linkbutton side ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: don't use foreach inside ASP.net webform. Use a repeater or a listview instead and you will be able to use binding `CommandArgument="<%# Item.Id %>"`

Comment: thanks for answer is there no any solution for foreach ?

Comment: This is not the way ASP.net webform has been designed. You will encounter a lot of issues if you continue using it this way. Why would you want to use a `foreach` statement ?

Answer (score 2):

`<%= %>` is equivalent to `Response.Write`, it outputs directly to the html markup. So it cannot write to server-side controls at all, since it does not know about them. In other words, what you are trying to do is impossible.

You should probably consider refactoring this `foreach` to Repeater, which gives control over controls as well as html:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td style="text-align: center">
            <span><%# Eval("Id") %></span>
        </td>
        ... same for other tds ...
        <td style="text-align: center">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbdetay" runat="server" OnClick="lbdetay_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CommandName="Detay">Detay</asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And don't forget to data bind it:

```
Repeater1.DataSource = list;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```